# BLE background scanning misses advertisements when phone unplugged

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I just finished developing an iOS app that can pick up readings from BLE peripherals in the background, even when the app is in a suspended state or has been closed by the OS. Even after a week or more, the app is still able to pick up readings.

Our BLE peripheral sends out advertisements at random (essentially) intervals and the device powers down after a very short time (on the order of seconds).

I would like to do the same with Android, but have only managed to do so by requesting to the user to disable battery optimizations via:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

I am really not happy with this solution, but when I remove this permission my app almost instantly stops working when the device is locked and unplugged. As a result, I believe that this has something to do with the [Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) feature.

Essentially what I am doing to scan (this is re-organized for brevity) is this:

**A) Scheduling a data collection job**

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(context, DataCollectionService.class);

jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, serviceName)
    .setPeriodic(900000)
    .setPersisted(true)
    .build();

jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

**B) This job (DataCollectionService.class) looks like this:**

```
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    context = this;
    bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

    // Omitted several checks for this post.

    scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(DataCollectionService.SERVICE_UUID)).build();
    builder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
    settings = builder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
            .build();

    scanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    if (scanFilter == null) {
        EventEmitter.sendError("Failed to get reference to bluetooth le scanner");
    }

    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.post(startRunnable);

    return true;
}
```

**C) Adding / requesting permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

and of course the permission that I want to avoid asking for:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

I also *programmatically* ask for location (since API 23) and battery optimization permissions.

---

I am mainly wondering if there is something that I'm doing that would cause my app to begin missing BLE peripheral advertisements so quickly after getting into this state (device locked and unplugged).

Comment: Did you try having a foreground service? That should prevent your app from being killed in the background and be affected by doze mode.

Comment: @Emil can you explain in a little more detail? Do you mean to remove `setPersisted`? Do you mean not using JobScheduler alltogether? Thanks!

Comment: Skip the job scheduler since that is used to run jobs periodically. You want to have your app active all the time. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services how to start a Foreground Service. As long as you have such a one in your app process, everything should be fine.

Comment: did you end up solving this issue?